# How to click a specified li for an autocomplete ul with Selenium IDE?

Tags: html, automated-tests, html-lists, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE for some test and trying to use it to select an specified option from an autocomplete. My problem is, the autocomplete is built in a `<ul>` and the two `<li>` possibles are identical. How to click a specified `li`? How to say to Selenium "click the first `li`" or "click the `li` with the text "apples"? I'm tried some ways that I found, but all are for other types of Selenium, and none are useful in Selenium IDE.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1003; top: 360.683px; left: 549.5px; display: block; width: 401px;">
  <li class="ac_item ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="clearfix ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
      <span class="c1">
        <b>Apple</b>
        <br>
        <span class="small secondary">Apples</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ac_item ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="clearfix ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
      <span class="c1">
        <b>Orange</b>
        <br>
        <span class="small secondary">Oranges</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selenium API gives you a number of ways to accomplish this. Since you don't have a traditional dropdown, you can't use the `select` command. Here are two solutions that click the second element in the autocomplete.

I created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/GYJW9) to test the solutions. The clicked element will turn red.

**Option 1:** Use a CSS locator.

```
| Command               | Target                                               |
| open                  | http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/GYJW9/embedded/result/ |
| waitForElementPresent | css=ul.ui-autocomplete                               |
| click                 | css=ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item:nth-child(2)  |
```

Note: Runs fast, and most people are comfortable with CSS, but this example requires that the targeted browser support the CSS3 nth-child selector.

**Option 2:** Use an XPath locator.

```
| Command               | Target                                               |
| open                  | http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/GYJW9/embedded/result/ |
| waitForElementPresent | css=ul.ui-autocomplete                               |
| click                 | //ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]/li[2]       |
```

Note: XPath are less familiar for most people and can be very slow compared to CSS locators, especially in IE.

For more ideas, check out the documentation for Selenium IDE on [locating elements](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements) and on the available [Selenese commands](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Selenium webdriver now. Much better.