# Clicking autocomplete menu item using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, autocomplete, automation

I am trying to test the auto complete feature in a search wizard wherein after sending search query, I have to click on the top menu item which would appear as auto complete just like it happens in Google search.

Below is the html structure that appears when I type `Text` in search bar:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-icons ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="partition_item ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <i class="autocomplete_icons autocomplete_city"></i>
        <span><b>Text A</b></span>
    </a>
</li>


<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="partition_item ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <i class="autocomplete_icons autocomplete_city"></i>
        <span><b>Text B</b></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I need to click the first menu item in auto complete which is `Text A` here in this case.
Below is what I have tried in java:

```
destinationInput.sendKeys(city);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ul.ui-autocomplete")));
    List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.className("partition_item"));
    listItems.get(0).click();
```

But nothing seems to happen. I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundException` at `listItems.get(0)` which i guess is because its unable to get the anchor tags inside ul element.

I also had gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459501/1471314) but am unable to incorporate it in java. Please guide.

Comment: Have you tried `listItems[0].click();`

Comment: @mutt: isn't that a compile time error ? `listItems[0]` ?

Comment: I'm rusty on java, but if its a list then it should be indexed and you should be able to just execute the click at the indexed object.  You have the list typed so it should understand it as a webelement.

Comment: No issues. I guess I had to find it via CSS Selector rather than class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css selector to find your element, smth like

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Css(".ui-autocomplete"))); 
List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.Css(".ui-menu-item"));
listItems[0].click();
```

Not sure about java syntax, but should work.