# How to select an item from dropdown list with Selenium IDE?

Tags: html, selenium, dropdown

how to make selection from dropdown list?

here is the html code

```
<span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--above" dir="ltr" style="width: 355px;">

<span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown">

<span class="select2-results">

<ul id="select2-31B9AC3E-5CBC-4FB3-83FF-951A88645FC9-results" class="select2-results__options" role="tree" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">

<li id="select2-31B9AC3E-5CBC-4FB3-83FF-951A88645FC9-result-98l8-11222" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Darbo partija</li>

<li id="select2-31B9AC3E-5CBC-4FB3-83FF-951A88645FC9-result-tyqm-11156" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Demokratinė darbo ir vienybės partija</li>
```

Comment: Vote for closure, unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have never used Selenium and even I understand the question...

Comment: @Pekka웃 There was no HTML code when I flagged it.

Comment: Yeah, it was entered the wrong way and not visible at the time.

Comment: Related, perhaps helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515747/how-to-click-a-specified-li-for-an-autocomplete-ul-with-selenium-ide

Comment: webDriver.findElement(By.Id("select2-31B9AC3E-5CBC-4FB3-83FF-951A88645FC9-results")).click(); webDriver.findElement(By.Id("the list item you want to click id")).click();?

Comment: Also that is not even the complete HTML. For example it is missing the ul end tag. Also what have you even tried?

Comment: @NamelessOne the duplicate seems to be about a normal `<select>` dropdown, though